# How can send speech with STM32F401 nucleo boards?

Tags: rs485, stm32f4, nucleo

I am working on stm32f401 nucleo boards and I want to communicate 2 boards each others with uart for sending speech.

I am using Nucleo-CCA02M1 mems microphone kits. Should I use which one? RS422 or RS485 for a full dublex communication?  Are there any example about that for helping?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use RS422 or RS485, you will need converter board to change uart to RS422 or RS485. Also, you do not need make any modification on your uart code to use any of them. These communication protocals are related with hardware. Uart, RS232, RS422 and RS485 are all serial communication. You can use any uart code for them.